# Burning a CD with "start track at 0:05" parameter applied in iTunes

Tags: itunes, cd-burning

I am about to burn a CD for a friend with iTunes (Windows). I have some of the songs in the playlist starting a few seconds into the track to eliminate unwanted elements such as talking. Will the CD burn with the start/end at settings applied or will it just burn the whole track?

Google and the iTunes help tutorials were unhelpful. I would just burn the CD and see if it works or not, but it's a physical CD and I really don't want to needlessly waste one.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually wrote a disk anyway. It turns out that iTunes does take those options into account and only writes the portion of the song that you have set to play.